# Jmeter: JDBC request : select statement: Multiple values from data set --Select * from table where table_id = '{CSV data set values}'

Tags: jmeter

I want to pass multiple values in select query in JDBC request(Thread count 1).

Select Query:- select a, b, c from d where table_id ='{uniqueValues}'

uniqueValues comes from CSV data set:

VariableName:- uniqueValues
file:-(this should be fixed length
123,254,569,789

i want to pass all these values from data sheet to query 1 go

select a, b, c from d where table_id =123,254,569,789 and so on..

I am not able to pass all the values in one go, 1 record for each thread is working.

I am trying to connect to DB run a query get the latest values in use in the http request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pass all the values from the CSV file in a single JDBC query this is not possible on:

- JMeter level, default [Sharing Mode setting of the CSV Data Set Config](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-csv-dataset-config) assumes that each thread reads next line from CSV on each iteration. Also [JMeter Variables are local to the thread](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) so you cannot use query results for another user with current user and vice versa
- SQL level, given you use `=` operator you're supposed to pass only one value, if you want to pass multiple values - take a look at [IN operator](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp)

In case your CSV file looks like:

```
table-id-1
table-id-2
etc.
```

and you want to pass all the values to a single query you need to amend it like

```
select a, b, c from d where table_id IN (${__groovy(new File('/path/to/your/file.csv').readLines().join('\,'),)})
```